TrustKit library implemenation is not working for me
public override func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, 
                                    task: URLSessionTask,
                                    didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge,
                                    completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        // Call into TrustKit here to do pinning validation
        if NetworkUtil.isTrustKitInitialized {
            if TrustKit.sharedInstance().pinningValidator.handle(challenge, completionHandler: completionHandler) == false {
                // TrustKit did not handle this challenge: perhaps it was not for server trust
                // or the domain was not pinned. Fall back to the default behavior
                completionHandler(.performDefaultHandling, nil)
            } else {
                // TrustKit did successfully handled this challenge and took decision based on trust chain
                DDLogDebug("SSL Pinning handled successfully")                
            }
        } else {
            completionHandler(.performDefaultHandling, nil)
        }
    }


//FILE: NetworkUtil.swift
static func initializeTrustKit(urlStr: String) {

    //urlStr is passed here as an argument based on the user's selection of environment
    if let sslKeys = Constants.SSLKeys(),
       let url = URL(string: urlStr),
       let domain = url.host {
        let trustKitConfig = [
            kTSKSwizzleNetworkDelegates: false,
            kTSKPinnedDomains: [
                domain: [
                    kTSKEnforcePinning: true,
                    kTSKIncludeSubdomains: true,
                    kTSKPublicKeyHashes: sslKeys
                ]
            ]
        ] as [String: Any]
        TrustKit.initSharedInstance(withConfiguration: trustKitConfig)
        isTrustKitInitialized = true
    }
}

We are using BurpSuite to trace the network (setting up a proxy server and routing iPhone to use a proxy) and we can read all communication in plaintext.
This code was working but looks like on the latest iOS it is not working. I request help here.
We are using BurpSuite to trace the network (setting up a proxy server and routing iPhone to use a proxy) and we can read all communication in plaintext.
This code was working but looks like on the latest iOS it is not working. I request help here.
